# Force query optimizer to use Primary key

Tags: mysql

I'm running a query that spans 3 tables, none of which have > 55K rows.  This query is taking 20+ seconds to run, which seems excessive:

```sql
SELECT
    `cp`.`author`,
    `cc`.`contents`
FROM
    `challenge_properties` as `cp`,
    `challenges` as `c`,
    `challenge_contents` as `cc`
WHERE
    `cp`.`followup_id` = `c`.`latest_followup` AND
    `cp`.`status` = 'new' AND
    `c`.`id` = `cp`.`challenge_id` AND
    `c`.`id` = `cc`.`challenge_id`
```

This is the result of `EXPLAIN`ing that query:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY,latest_followup_index
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 13817
        Extra: 
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: cc
         type: ref
possible_keys: challenge_id
          key: challenge_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: cts.c.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: cp
         type: ref
possible_keys: challenge_id,followup_id
          key: followup_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: cts.c.latest_followup
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
```

As you can see, the first table, `challenges` has a primary key, but it's not being used.  I've tried adding the `FORCE KEY(PRIMARY)` clause to the `challenges` table declaration, but it's still not used.

What can I do to speed up this query?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is selecting ALL records from the `challenges` table — therefore there is no need to use any index on the records from that table. Basically MySQL is selecting every record in `challenges`, then finding matching records in the other two tables.

Couldn't you just leave out the `challenges` table all together? You're not selecting data from that table, and the only time that table would limit the data selected would be if your other tables had invalid `challenge_id`s, which foreign keys can take care of...

```
SELECT
    `cp`.`author`,
    `cc`.`contents`
FROM
    `challenge_properties` as `cp`,
    `challenge_contents` as `cc`
WHERE
    `cp`.`status` = 'new' AND
    `cp`.`challenge_id` = `cc`.`challenge_id`
```

EDIT: You say you can't remove the `challenges` table from the query... I would try specifying your `JOIN` conditions in the `JOIN` clause instead of the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT
    `cp`.`author`,
    `cc`.`contents`
FROM `challenge_properties` as `cp`
JOIN `challenges` as `c`
    ON `cp`.`challenge_id` = `c`.`id`
    AND `cp`.`followup_id` = `c`.`latest_followup`
JOIN `challenge_contents` as `cc`
    ON `cc`.`challenge_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `cp`.`status` = 'new'
```

The query optimizer might already do this for you, but it doesn't hurt to try it, and I think it's easier to see how the joins are happening with this syntax.

You could also try adding another index to `challenge_properties` on `( challenge_id, followup_id )`, and another to `challenges` on `( challenge_id, latest_followup )` — the complex key might help MySQL work quicker. But it's also possible that the problem might be outside your query... usually when you `EXPLAIN` and see only one table with big numbers in the `rows` column, your query is pretty well optimized. MySQL is only looking at one row in `challenge_properties` and one row in `challenge_contents`, and scanning every row in `challenges` to find a match.

EDIT 2:

Unfortunately, I'm not sure what else can be done to optimize this query. You can get slightly more performance if the indexes used (`cc.challenge_id` and `cp.followup_id`) are `UNIQUE NOT NULL` indexes, and you should get better performance with a complex index for `cp` on `(cp.challenge_id, cp.followup_id)`. This would turn those `type: ref` into `type: eq_ref`, which is slightly better. But that's about it... do you not have problems with any other queries? Your query should theoretically return 13817 rows... is the amount of data possibly the problem? Does it speed up significantly if you just select `COUNT(*)` instead of returning all the rows?

Comment: I can't remove the `challenges` table, because I'm also matching on the `latest_followup` field from `challenges`

Comment: The changes didn't improve performance at all.  The EXPLAIN-ation wasn't any different either.

What I don't understand is why the query isn't using the PRIMARY key, as it's an index of ids - which is exactly what I'm matching against.  Why is it scanning each row?

Comment: @Pickle Using the PK index wouldn't help here, since MySQL would look through 13817 entries in the index, then pull the corresponding row and check it against your joins. Instead, it's just looking through 13817 row and checking those rows directly - which is actually quicker.

Comment: Running the query again today goes much quicker - < 2 seconds.  I wonder if this slowness was just due to server load.  In any case, if the query can't be optimized any further, than so be it - no sense beating a dead horse.